# Creation Of Simple LR Parser Closure items

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, parser-generator

Suppose The G (augmented Grammar):

```
E' - > E
E  - > E+T|T
T  - > T*F|F
F -  > (E)|id
```

So in one of the levels of creation of the dfa , I had reached to this :(I6 in dragon book)

```
    I6                   I9
 ---------            ---------
|E -> E+.T|          | E->E+T. |   
|T -> .T*F|     T    | T->T.*F |
|T -> .F  |  ----->   ---------
|F -> .(E)|       
|F -> .id |
 ---------
```

I am wondering , why we don't add the `T->.F` and `F->.(E)` and `F->.id` to I9 ?

When We Reach T in input string , we should Add T->.F and Now we have reached to F and we should Add F->.(E) and F->.id.

Why I9 won't contains those ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the how the closure and goto algorithms works. Since when you create I9 by using GOTO(T) on I6 the dot moves one step to the right over any T and add those to a new set. This set is then the I9 GOTO set. Those that do not have a T to the right of the dot in I6 will not get added to the I9 GOTO set. After doing the GOTO you get set I9

```
E->E+T.
T->T.*F
```

When you apply closure on set I9 you expand every nonterminal on the right of the dot. On I9 you have no non-terminals to the right of the dot so there is nothing to expand.

I recently made a post about a very similar albeit a bit more complex problem that might be of help if you need additional clarification, [Computing LR1 closure](http://binarysculpting.com/2012/02/04/computing-lr1-closure/)